# ASP.NET Download a SFTP file using the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, sftp

I was trying to download a SFTP file(.csv) using C# and asp.net, but all the examples needs me to have a remote file directory.

For this case, I need the browser to download the file, not me to put in the the directory, since the browser(client) will not have access to put files directly into a directory.

Have, anyone done this before?

I was trying to use SSH.NET, but didnt find a way to do it.

Comment: "a SFTP file". SFTP is Secure FTP, a protocol, not a type of file. It's completely unclear what you are asking or how it is related to ASP.NET.

Comment: Unless the browser has the ability to work with SFTP (something you probably can't rely on) then the browser won't be involved in this. Your server would need the appropriate libraries. It'd need to download the file, then allow the user to download the file from your web server just like any other file.

Comment: You may consider writing a handler that can stream a file from an sftp server and immediately write the bytes to an http response stream, thus your server becomes an adapter on behalf of a browser (that doesn't understand sftp) and an sftp server ( that doesn't understand http)

Comment: its kinda impossible to tell from your question. however a really good libary for sftp is winscp https://winscp.net has a wealth of documentation and examples

Comment: I meant download a file that I have on a server that I acces via SFTP, download it using the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this, by moving the file to my server using SFTP and then downloading the file normaly.

```
 string host = @"host";
        string username = "user";
        string password = "pass";
        string remoteDirectory = "/remote";

        string localDirectory = Server.MapPath(@"\pdf\");

        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
        {
            sftp.Connect();
            var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string remoteFileName = file.Name;
                if (remoteFileName == "APADEAATTT.csv")
                {

                    using (Stream file1 = File.OpenWrite(localDirectory + "APADEAATTT.csv"))
                    {
                        sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory + "APADEAATTT.csv", file1);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localDirectory+"APADEAATTT.csv");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
        Response.End();
```